# ALTER COLUMN "active" TYPE boolean USING "active"::boolean

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-migration

I am currently working through "Django 3 By Example" by Antonio Mele.  Chapter 3 has me working through creating a blog application.  In the chapter it has me change my database from MySQL to PostgreSQL and then migrate the data.  When I migrate the data I get this error:

> **django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type timestamp with time zone to boolean LINE 1: ..." ALTER COLUMN "active" TYPE boolean
> USING "active"::boolean**

I have gone through some PostgreSQL documentation and back through my code but I am unable to complete the migrate due to this error.  I have been stuck at this same place for quite some time and can not seem to isolate the correction for the error.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include your migration file and then the output from `python manage.py sqlmigrate [your_migration_here]`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have figured out my problem, 'active' is a BooleanField and the migration cast it as DateTimeField.

```
# Generated by Django 3.1 on 2020-08-18 23:58

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('blog', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Comment',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=80)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254)),
                ('body', models.TextField()),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                **('active', models.DateTimeField(default=True))**,
                ('post', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='comments', to='blog.post')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('created',),
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Here is the sqlmigrate output:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Comment
--
CREATE TABLE "blog_comment" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "name" varchar(80) NOT NULL, "email" varchar(254) NOT NULL, "body" text NOT NULL, "created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "updated" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "active" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "post_id" integer NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE "blog_comment" ADD CONSTRAINT "blog_comment_post_id_580e96ef_fk_blog_post_id" FOREIGN KEY ("post_id") REFERENCES "blog_post" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE INDEX "blog_comment_post_id_580e96ef" ON "blog_comment" ("post_id");
COMMIT;
```